# How to append obtained char values in a loop into a String, to pass it to ShellExecute()?

Tags: c, pointers, visual-studio-code, shellexecute

If the variable **'S'** is inside a *for loop*, which stores the ***char*** value of the Binary value inputted by the user,
how to append all the characters to form a String which I can pass to a ShellExecute() fucntion.

```
char *u="https://google.com"; 
ShellExecute(NULL, "open",u, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL); //this will open a webpage
```

**^^^** **Binary values should be input in such a way that 'u' is a URL** that opens  in the browser. This will be taken care by the user. Just referenced it.

### The following, is to convert Binary -> Dec-> Char:

```
for(i=0; i<21; i++)
scanf("%ld",&n[i]);                        //Binary

for(i=0; i<21;i++)
{
   k=n[i], c=0, decimalNumber=0;
   while(k!=0)
    {
     remainder  = k%10;
     k /=  10;
     decimalNumber +=  remainder*pow(2,c); //Dec
     ++c;
    }
      char S=decimalNumber;                //Char
      .
      .  //how do I join all the Char I am getting here in one String
      .
 }
```

Using **this way** causes **A LOT OF ISSUES**, but this was the only way I figured after doing a ton of reading...

```
char  *u1=NULL;
char  *u=NULL; //just after void main()
.
.
.  //after I store char in 'S'
u1=u; //'u1' stores the string as 'u' gets deallocated every loop
size_t len=strlen(u1);
u=malloc(len +  1  +  1 );
strcat(u,u1); //copies the value of 'u1' from previous iteration to 'u'
u[len]=t;
u[len+1]='\0';
```

How do I store the characters in a String variable ?

Any small help is highly appreciated, Thanks! :)

Comment: `printf("%s",u);` is printing garbage __before__ `ShellExecute` is called, so it's unrelated to `ShellExecute`. And your code is not infected, it just contains bug. You need to debug this. And what is `printf("%s",u);` suposed to print and what do you `ShellExecute` expect to do?

Comment: Oh I see it now, there are many other issues. You should read the chapter dealing with strings in your C text book.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Just because the effect is before the cause doesn’t mean it’s unrelated. In fact, it’s a well-known hallmark of undefined behaviour that it can have effects “in the past”, so to speak. See [*Undefined behavior can result in time travel* by Raymond Chen](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633).

Comment: @KonradRudolph it is true, but then there should be an attempt at creating a [mcve] that would *ensure* that it is not a case of UB travelling backwards in time...

Comment: There are less lines in the code than there are *errors*.

Comment: What is you code supposed to do? Please [edit]  your question and show an example of input and expected output and explain what the program is supposed to do.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of issues in your code which may lead to memory corruption.

```
char  *u1=malloc (sizeof  25);
```

I presume this is supposed to allocate 25 characters? it actually allocates `sizeof(25)` or `sizeof(int)` characters which is probably 4. You just need `malloc(25)`.

```
char  *u="";
```

This creates a read only empty string literal, you cannot modify its value.

```
u1=u;
```

This throws away the string you previously allocated and causes a memory leak.

```
strcat(u,u1)
```

The memory in u is uninitialised, you need to call `memset(u, 0, len + 2)` before you call this otherwise `u1` will be appended after the first null character in `u`, `u` may well not contain any null characters so `u1` could be written anywhere in memory.

Answer (score 1):

You have a mistake there, which might well explain the garbage:

```
     u=malloc(len +  1  +  1 );
     strcat(u,u1);
```

On the `malloc` line (at the first iteration), you lose the `u` that was initialized by `char  *u="";`.
The `malloc` might return an uninitalized memory area (with garbage), and `strcat` copies `u1` AFTER the garbage.